I can't convert 46809654.36 into a date and time value in Google Sheets
I used the formula:
= ArrayFormula(SUM(min(A2:A1294)*(U2:U1294="")))

The A column contains timestamps,
and I got the result "46809654.36".
I want to convert this to a format like "2020. 5. 1 pm 5:27:01",
but it won't change. How can I fix this?

Your result 46809654.36 is wrong, it cannot be converted to a human reading date-time string. Without knowing what your data is in your sheet, no help can be offered.

Use filter(), like this:
=min(filter(A2:A1294, U2:U1294 = ""))

See filter().

Thanks, I realized later that my formula was wrong.
what i did was
=minifs($A1:$A,$U1:$U,""))
:)

How amusing.
Another random restriction in Excel and Google sheets. There is absolutely no reason why you shouldn't be able to convert an arbitrary real number into date format but it goes haywire when you exceed 31/12/9999.
If Excel was able to handle 46809654.36  as a date it would be converted to something like Sept 130057 - and that is a very long way into the future. Probably nothing like the answer you were expecting.
I think the problem here is that you don't want SUM() of the dates that match your criterion you want their AVERAGE() value or even just MIN(). It really isn't clear what you hope to achieve by adding dates together.
They have an arbitrary baseline for day zero. Excel's being far more arbitrary than any other standard date representations like for example Julian day.
Excel has some very weird behaviour with the baseline for dates set at 0/1/1900 == 0 - a reference date that you cannot sensibly enter as a date without having it left justified as a string in "date" format.
However you can enter numeric zero 0 and format that as a correctly justified numeric date. This is a table of the stress dates for Excel:



Day (General format)
Date formatted




-1
##########


0
00/01/1900


1
01/01/1900


2
02/01/1900






2958464
30/12/9999


2958465
31/12/9999


2958466
##########




Thanks, I realized later that my formula was wrong. what i did was =minifs($A1:$A,$U1:$U,""))
:)
